# Negative selecting without direct path in CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want the following selector to match only those `<span>` elements that are direct children of `'.grand-grand-child'` and not descendants of `'.grand-grand-parent'`:

```
:not(.grand-grand-parent) .grand-grand-child > span { 
  color: blue; 
}
```

But it fails to apply the rule. Is it possible to solve the problem without Javascript? In my experience, `:not` rules at the beginning have to be followed with direct path made with `>` signs. Am I right?

Comment: They don’t *have* to be, but this probably won’t do what you want (if what you want is `.grand-grand-child:not(.some-grand-grand-parent *)`). Normally you’d do it by applying styles to `.grand-grand-child > span` and reversing them in `.some-grand-grand-parent .grand-grand-child > span`.

Comment: `:not(.some-grand-grand-parent *)` is not supported by Chrome (at least at the moment), this selector is just ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See, there's a problem here: the first part of this selector will be applied to any element in the second selector's match ancestor chain (in attempt to match the whole rule). Consider the following:

```css
:not(.parent) .child {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
      Which color am I?
  </div>
</div>
```

And the answer is blue, even though that `.child` element is clearly matched by `.parent .child` rule. The problem is, this rule reads as

> match any element with class 'child' if **one of its ancestors** is without class 'parent'

And of course, it has such an ancestor - `<body>` element. Now compare with this fragment:

```css
:not(.parent) > .child {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
      Which color am I?
  </div>
</div>
```

And now the answer is black, as the selector reads as...

> match any element with class 'child' if **its direct parent** is without class 'parent'

Another way will be opened when browsers start supporting [**CSS Selectors Level 4 negation spec**](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#negation), allowing something more than [**simple selector**](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#simple) as `:not` argument. It'll be possible to write something like:

```
.child:not(.parent *) { /* */ }
```

And now if *any* element is ancestor chain of `.child` matches `.parent`, it's not matched. But both Chrome and Firefox at the moment of writing still lack support of this feature - they only support [**CSS Level 3 negation**](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#negation).

Comment: I just want descendant to be red because there is NOT grand parent in second rule but the browser matches it.

Comment: I run the code snippet you have provided and descendand is blue. It shoud be matched by the first rule and not the second one.

Comment: I asked about it because I wanted to now if it is possible to solve this problem with CSS. And I don't understand why some people thing that this is a bad question.

Comment: You are right, I have to wait for CSS4 and hack it with Javascript now.

Comment: Rewrote the answer to clarify the explanation a bit. Yes, as it stands you either rewrite the rules or cover the distance with JS.